# Java creates additional element under root element

Tags: java, xml, doctype

So I have an XML file that looks like the following:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
 <!DOCTYPE config SYSTEM "config.dtd">
 <config>
 <domains>
 </domains>
 </config>
```

I need to create a new element called session with two attributes let's call this atrib 1 and atrib 2.

So ultimately I would like the XML file to look like this.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
 <!DOCTYPE config SYSTEM "config.dtd">
 <config>
 <session atrib1="100" artib2="200" />
 <domains>
 </domains>
 </config>
```

I've been playing around with the document builder but cannot seem to figure out how to get this to work.

Below is the modified version from the tips below.  The new element is not being created and the    &  is being removed from the xml file.

```
         File file = new File(fileLocaton);
         DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
         document = docBuilder().parse(file);

         Element rootElement = document.getDocumentElement();
         Element sSession = document.createElement("session");
         // set attributes
         sSession.setAttribute("attr1", "100");
         sSession.setAttribute("attr2", "200");
         // instead of appending, insert in front of the first child
         rootElement.insertBefore(sSession, rootElement.getFirstChild());

         DOMSource source = new DOMSource(document);
         TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
         Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
         StreamResult result = new StreamResult(file.getPath());
         transformer.transform(source, result);
```

Comment: of course it only creates the session with a closing tag. You don't set the attribute name and values.

Comment: So, you can convert your document to string, prepend it with ?xml and doctype(defined literally) and write it to file with FileWriter(or something you like).

Comment: When I run your code, I see the <?xml… prolog in the output, as well as a full `<session/>` element.  To make the DOCTYPE appear in the output, add: `transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.DOCTYPE_SYSTEM, "config.dtd");`

Comment: That seemed to work.  How do i make it nicely formatted, like the session element on a new line?

Comment: Any suggestions on the formatting?  It also put it's right at the top, what if i wanted it after <domain> tag?